# 'Creating maven-archtype-quickstart' has encountered a prob

Tags: java, maven, proxy

I installed maven 3.3.3 and the install was successful.

However, while trying to create a maven project in eclipse I am getting the below error

```
'Creating maven-archtype-quickstart' has encountered a problem

Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:1.1 from any of the configured repositories.
Could not resolve artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.archetypes:maven-archetype-quickstart:pom:1.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection refused: connect
```

I've added proxy details to my settings.xml (got it from my browser) with/without username password

```
<proxies>
  <proxy>
    <id>462603</id>
    <active>true</active>
    <protocol>http</protocol>
    <username>com\462603</username>
    <password>xxxxxxxx</password>
    <host>proxy.company.com</host>
    <port>6050</port>
    <nonProxyHosts>10.*|*.company.com</nonProxyHosts>
  </proxy>
</proxies>
```

I listed this settings.xml in Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->Maven->User Settings

Also added the archtype http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml in Eclipse->Windows->Preferences->Maven->Archtype

Apart from all this the error still persists

I am aware there are many such duplicate question, but the solutions mentioned in all of it didn't work

Answer (score -1):

Keep Connected to internet,

Step 1:-  Delete .m2 folder

Step 2:- Open Eclipse click on Window->Preferences

Step 3:- Pop-Up will display , Click Maven-> Archetype

Step 4:-  Click on "add remote catalog"

Step 5:- Enter the deatil

```
        CATALOG FILE = https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml
         DESCRIPTION = maven_catalog
```

Step 6:- Click on Verify , After the verification hit Ok .

Comment: Where is `.m2` folder?